# Специализация шаблона функции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте люди добрые! Решаю задачку по плюсам, суть такая, что не могу написать специализацию шаблона функции - компилятор ругается.
Суть задачки - при передачи числового массива (и кол-ва элементов, конечно) тупо найти наибольшее и вернуть, но доп. условие - эта самая специализация класса, чтобы при передаче массива указателей на char вернуть указатель на самую длинную строку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

template <typename T> T maxn(const T [], int);          // шаблон
template <> char * maxn(const char * [], int);          // специализация

int main()
{
    int arInt[6] = {1, 2, 3, 777, 7, 9};
    double arDouble[4] = {228.1, 88.3, 1.0, 4.5};
    const char * arPtr[5] =
    {
        "qwertyuiop",
        "asdfdgjhdfkjdfjk",
        "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
        "skhkshjksg",
        "ksjdhfkbsfhksdjhfsdhfjk"
    };

    cout << "for arInt:" << endl;
    cout << "result: " << maxn(arInt, 6) << endl << endl;

    cout << "for arDouble:" << endl;
    cout << "result: " << maxn(arDouble, 4) << endl << endl;

    cout << "for arPtr:" << endl;
    cout << "result: " << maxn(arPtr, 5) << endl;

    return 0;
}

template <typename T> T maxn(const T arr[], int n)
{
    T result = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (arr[i] > result)
            result = arr[i];
    return result;
}

template <> char * maxn(const char * arr[], int n)
{
    char * result = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        if (strlen(arr[i]) > strlen(arr[i - 1]))
            result = arr[i];
    return result;
}
```

Ругается компилятор следующим образом:

8_6.cpp:20:20: ошибка: идентификатор шаблона «maxn<>» для «char* maxn(const char**, int)» не соответствует никакой декларации шаблона
 template <> char * maxn(const char * [], int);   // специализация
                    ^~~~

8_6.cpp:19:25: замечание: candidate is: template T maxn(const T*, int)
 template  T maxn(const T [], int);   // шаблон

Подскажите что не так делаю, ибо только осваиваю шаблоны эти, перерыл, а что не так - не пойму, хоть убей..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


template <class type_elem> 
type_elem max(const std::vector<type_elem> &v) {
    auto result = v[0];
    for(const auto &elem: v) {
        if (elem > result) {
            result = elem;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

template<>
std::string max(const std::vector<std::string> &v) {
    auto result = v[0];
    for(const auto &elem: v) {
        if (elem.length() > result.length()) {
            result = elem;
        }
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> vint= {1, 2, 3, 777, 7, 9};
    std::vector<double> vdouble = {228.1, 88.3, 1.0, 4.5};
    std::vector<std::string> vstring = {
        "qwertyuiop",
        "asdfdgjhdfkjdfjk",
        "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq",
        "skhkshjksg",
        "ksjdhfkbsfhksdjhfsdhfjk"
    };

    std::cout << "vint max: " << max(vint) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "vdouble max: " << max(vdouble) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "vstring max: " << max(vstring) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Согласен, так работает - только суть в том, что упражнение заключается в написании именно специализации именно шаблону функции. Но в любом случае - спасибо!

Comment: @anonanon поправил

Comment: В коде по-прежнему нет специализации шаблона функции. Если "упражнение заключается в написании именно специализации именно шаблону функции", то почему ответ помечен как "принятый"?

Comment: ? При любом типе возвращаеться max, при std::string max.length() Разве это не специализация?

Comment: Специализация шаблона в С++ - особая фича языка, объявляемая через синтаксис `template <...`. У вас в коде нет никакой специализации  вообще. Вы вместо специализации  сделали обычную перегрузку функции.

Comment: У меня с вами что разные языки?) https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kwyxac18.aspx

Comment: Ым... Не понял. Это такая шутка? Вы исправили свой код после моих комментариев, заменили таки перегрузку на специализацию, а теперь делаете вид, что не понимаете, о чем я говорю?

Comment: Ааа. " 
Специализация шаблона в С++ - особая фича языка, объявляемая через синтаксис template <.... У вас в коде нет никакой специализации вообще. Вы вместо специализации сделали обычную перегрузку функции. – AnT 9 минут назад" 9. " 
изменён 10 минут назад" 10 .  10 > 9

Comment: "В коде по-прежнему нет специализации шаблона функции" - AnT 19 минут назад. "Разве это не специализация?" – Andrio Skur 16 минут назад. "Специализация шаблона в С++ - особая фича языка, объявляемая через синтаксис template <"  AnT 15 минут назад. Изменён 15 минут назад.

Comment: Тогда действительно был чуть другой код. Я не вижу практической разницы между перезагрузкой и специализацией, а так как вы все таки к этому "прицепились", я и поправил это дело(если можно назвать правкой добавление "template<>"). Но эта правка была до сообщения "Специализация шаблона в С++ - особая фича языка, объявляемая через синтаксис template <.... У вас в коде нет никакой специализации вообще. "

Comment: Это бы скорее вопрос к автору исходного вопроса @anon anon: почему после им же озвученного требования "упражнение заключается в написании именно специализации именно шаблону функции" (с двумя "именно"!) он вдруг отметил ответ, в котором нет (т.е. тогда не было) никакой специализации.

Answer (score 6):

Тип `const char *[]` соответствует типу `T[]` при `T == const char *`. Т.е. тип `const char *[]` - это массив с *неконстантными* элементами. Тип `const char *[]` никак не может соответствовать типу `const T[]` ни при каком `T`.

У вас в главном шаблоне параметр объявлен именно как `const T[]`, а в явной специализации указан параметр типа `const char *[]`.  Компилятор никак не сможет увидеть в этом явную специализацию главного шаблона, ибо не существует такого `T`, при котором `const T[]` будет соответствовать `const char *[]`.

Если вы хотите, чтобы такое соответствие было возможным, специализация должна объявлять свой параметр как массив с *константными* элементами: `const char *const []`. При этом первый `const` опционален (он входит внутрь `T`).

Корректные варианты объявления явных специализаций данного шаблона могут выглядеть так

```
template <> char *maxn(char *const [], int);              // T == char *
template <> const char *maxn(const char *const [], int);  // T == const char *
```

но не так, как у вас.

Comment: Дело действительно в соответствии контстантного-неконстантного. Буду вникать в это глубже. Спасибо, @AnT